How to Integrate Persistent Outbox with Quartz Scheduler?
I'm using a persistent outbox pattern. Additionally, I'm using Quartz Scheduler to periodically check the outbox and resend the failed messages. Unfortunally redelivery doesn't work together with persistent outbox.
I'm using .net8, masstransit 8.2.3
I tried changing the persistent outbox to in memory and it started working, unfortunately it needs a persistent outbox.
Here is the code:

services.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
{
    var schedulerEndpointAddress = new Uri($"{rabbitSettings.Host}/{rabbitSettings.VHost}/quartz");
    var redeliveryPolicy = new []
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
    };

    configurator.AddMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpointAddress);
    configurator.AddQuartzConsumers();
    configurator.AddQuartz();
    configurator.AddQuartzHostedService();

    configurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    configurator.AddConsumer<CreateSingleDailyPaymentConsumer>(consumerConfigurator =>
    {
        consumerConfigurator.UseScheduledRedelivery(retryConfigurator =>
            retryConfigurator.SetRetryPolicy(filter => filter.Intervals(redeliveryPolicy)));
    });

    configurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host($"{rabbitSettings.Host}/{rabbitSettings.VHost}", hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Username(rabbitSettings.Username);
            hostConfigurator.Password(rabbitSettings.Password);
            hostConfigurator.Heartbeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter("nfbg-"));
        cfg.DeployPublishTopology = true;
        //cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox(context); it works with in memory
    });
    
    configurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<FuneralConsumerContext>(outboxConfigurator =>
    {
        outboxConfigurator.UseSqlServer();
        outboxConfigurator.UseBusOutbox();
    });

    configurator.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, endpointConfigurator) =>
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpointAddress);
        endpointConfigurator.UseEntityFrameworkOutbox<FuneralConsumerContext>(context);
    });
});


